# Using AutoMapper for classes with constructors and nested lists

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, automapper

I have two entities: User, and UserQuota. "User" contains a list of quotas.
I need to map from these classes to DTO objects: UserWebDtoWithQuotas and UserQuotaWebDto, where UserWebDtoWithQuotas would also contain a list of UserQuotaWebDto's.

I tend to use strict constructors when defining classes in my project, so my DTOs look something like this:

```
public record UserWebDtoWithQuotas
{
    public Guid UserId { get; private init; }
    public string Username { get; private init; }
    public List<UserQuotaWebDto> Quotas { get; private init; }

    public UserWebDtoWithQuotas(Guid userId, string username, List<UserQuotaWebDto> quotas)
    {
        UserId = userId;
        Username = username;
        Quotas = quotas;
    }
}
```

I tried just defining two mapping rules, like this:

```
    CreateMap<User, UserWebDtoWithQuotas>();
    CreateMap<UserQuota, UserQuotaWebDto>();
```

But this throws an error "Type 'Application.Operations.Users.DTOs.UserWebDtoWithQuotas' does not have a default constructor (Parameter 'type')".
I tried to use ".constructUsing" in the mapper profile, and it works when it's just one line of code:

```
CreateMap<User, UserWebDtoWithQuotas>()
        .ConvertUsing(user => new UserWebDtoWithQuotas(user.Id, user.Username, new List<UserQuotaWebDto>()));
```

But then I tried to actually map the nested list somehow, like this:

```
CreateMap<User, UserWebDtoWithQuotas>()
        .ConstructUsing((user, context) =>
        {
            var quotas = context.Mapper.Map<List<UserQuotaWebDto>>(user.Quotas);
            return new UserWebDtoWithQuotas(user.Id, user.Username, quotas);
        });
```

And it throws the same "no default constructor" again.

What am I doing wrong? Is it at all possible to make complex custom rules for constructing objects?

Comment: A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code.
UserQuota.cs

```
    public record UserQuota
    {
        public string quotaA { get; set; }
        public string quotaB { get; set; }
    }
```

UserQuotaWebDto.cs

```
    public record UserQuotaWebDto
    {
        public string quotaA { get; set; }
        public string quotaB { get; set; }
    }
```

User.cs

```
    public record User
    {
        public Guid UserId { get; private init; }
        public string Username { get; private init; }
        public List<UserQuota> Quotas { get; private init; }

        public User(Guid userId, string username, List<UserQuota> quotas)
        {
            UserId = userId;
            Username = username;
            Quotas = quotas;
        }
    }
```

UserWebDtoWithQuotas.cs

```
    public record UserWebDtoWithQuotas
    {
        public Guid UserId { get; private init; }
        public string Username { get; private init; }
        public List<UserQuotaWebDto> Quotas { get; private init; }

        public UserWebDtoWithQuotas(Guid userId, string username, List<UserQuotaWebDto> quotas)
        {
            UserId = userId;
            Username = username;
            Quotas = quotas;
        }
    }
```

test controller

```
        [HttpGet("test")]
        public void test()
        {
            MapperConfiguration configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                // TestA -> TestB
                cfg.CreateMap<UserQuota, UserQuotaWebDto>();
                cfg.CreateMap<User, UserWebDtoWithQuotas>();
            });
            IMapper mapper = configuration.CreateMapper();


            User user1 = new User(Guid.NewGuid(), "Tom", new List<UserQuota>() { new UserQuota() { quotaA = "qA1", quotaB = "qB1" }, new UserQuota() { quotaA = "qA2", quotaB = "qB2" } });
            UserWebDtoWithQuotas user2 = mapper.Map<UserWebDtoWithQuotas>(user1);
            Console.WriteLine("user1:"+JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user1));
            Console.WriteLine("user2:"+JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user2));
        }
```

output
[image]

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks to your example I narrowed down the problem. Your example works, and when I modified my code to use "mapper.Map()" - it worked for me as well.
But it throws an error when I try using LINQ extension .ProjectTo<UserWebDtoWithQuotas>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider), even though configs are the same. 
I wonder why is that, but I can just use mapping directly from now on.